# Detecta si el usuario tiene internet con Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Desarrollé un comercio electrónico y estoy usando webview en android. Pero me gustaría detectar si el usuario está conectado a Internet antes de dirigirlo al comercio electrónico.  ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto con Kotlin?  Mi código es así:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        title = "Delivery"
        val window: Window = this@MainActivity.window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.black)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val webView = binding.webView
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("https://delivery.site.com.br/")
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val webView = binding.webView
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack()
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar la clase `ConectivityManager` y la función `getNetworkCapabilities()` de la clase `NetworkCapabilities`.

Esta sería una función a usar en Kotlin:

```
fun existeConexion(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                // NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                // NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                // NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Puedes llamar la anterior función antes de cargar la url en el WebView:

```
 if(existeConexion(applicationContext)){
    //Existe conexión a internet.
    val webView = binding.webView
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl("https://delivery.site.com.br/")
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
  }else{
     //No existe conexión a internet!
  }
```

Comment: Hola jorgesys. Ahora estoy aprendiendo Kotlin. En caso de que el usuario navegue por las páginas y se caiga el internet. ¿Cómo haría en ese caso?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más rápido es comprobar si hay una red disponible, pero puede existir la posibilidad de estar conectado a una red pero que no tiene salida a internet, para ello se debe comprobar enviando un ping.

```kotlin
object NetworkUtils {
 
    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
    fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork) ?: return false
            return when {
                networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) -> true
                networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else @Suppress("deprecation") {
            val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo ?: return false
            return activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
        }
    }
 
    @RequiresPermission(anyOf = [Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.INTERNET])
    fun isInternetReachable(context: Context): Boolean {
        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            //Network is available, check if internet is reachable
            try {
                val httpConnection: HttpURLConnection = URL("https://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                    .openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android")
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close")
                httpConnection.connectTimeout = 1500
                httpConnection.connect()
 
                return httpConnection.responseCode == 204
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return false
    }
 
    fun openInternetConnectivityPanel(context: Context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
            startActivity(context, panelIntent, null)
        }
    }
 
}
```

### Detectar si hay red

Con `isNetworkAvailable` se puede detectar si el dispositivo está conectado a una red

```kotlin
if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
    //Hay conexión a una red
}
```

### Detectar si hay internet

Con `isInternetReachable` se puede detectar si hay internet, en caso de no haber internet, tarda unos 15 segundos en devolver la llamada

```kotlin
if (NetworkUtils.isInternetReachable(this)) {
   //La conexión tiene salida a Internet
}
```

#### Permisos necesarios

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Extraido de: [Métodos de verificar la conexión a internet para Android usando Kotlin](https://dev4phones.wordpress.com/2022/10/02/metodos-de-verificar-la-conexion-a-internet-para-android-usando-kotlin/)